# On values of $n\geq 1$ satisfying that for all primorial $N_k$ less than $n$ the difference $n-N_k$ is a prime number

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

In this post I present a similar question that shows section **A19** of [1], I was inspired in it to define my sequence and question. I am asking about it since I think that the problem that arises from my question harmonizes with this.

For integers $k\geq 1$ we denote the primorial of order $k$ as $N_k$, that is

$$N_k=\prod_{r=1}^k p_r$$

where thus $p_r$ denotes the $r-th$ prime number. I add as reference that Wikipedia has the article [*Primorial.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)

In next paragraph $n\geq 1 $ denotes the integer variable.

**Definition.** *Now we consider the values of* $n$ *making* $n-N_k$ *prime for all those primorials* $N_k$ *satisfying* $2\leq N_k<n$.

I've calculated the first few terms from the definition. Our sequence starts as $$n=4,9,25,43,49,73\ldots...$$

To illustrate our sequence we add the example about why $25$ is in our sequence: the only primorials less than $n=25$ are $N_1=2$ and $N_2=6$, and we get that the integers $25-2$ and $25-6$ are both prime numbers.

I have no idea/intutition if this sequence has only a finite number of terms.

> **Question.** I don't know if it exists only a finite number of positive integers $n's$ being $$n-N_k$$ a prime number for all primorial $2\leq N_k<n$. What work can be done to study if the sequence of $n's$ from this definition  should have a finite number of terms? **Many thanks.**

I am asking if it is possible to deduce a proposition, get some idea about it, or set some conjecture.

**I emphasize** that I am asking about what work or statements/heuristics we can get for the **Question,** since it is a hard question (see the comments) I think that I should accept an available and useful answer.

### References:

[1] Richard K. Guy, *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, Unsolved problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag (1994).

Comment: To prove that the sequence is infinite is at least as hard as to prove that both $n-2$ and $n-6$ are prime for infinitely many $n$ which seems out of reach.

Comment: I was asking from the ignorance about the difficulty of the problem that I propose and therefore technical details like the one you have provided I did not know. If there is more activity for this post feel free to add your nice contribution and related 
thoughts as an answer. Many thanks @DmitryKrachun

Comment: I think this requires the $m$-th term of your sequence to be coprime with the first $m^{1+o(1)}$ primes.

Comment: Note also that the terms you listed are all primes or powers of primes.

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable comments, as I've said to the other user, feel free to add your remarks if you want as an answer @SylvainJULIEN when you consider it. On the other hand I've calculated only the previous few terms that were showed.

Comment: I would like to add a comment, with all respect, to evoke the importance/relevance of the book in the references written by the mathematician Richard K. Guy. 
I wish I had known these kind of unsolved problem books in other subjects that I studied (I've studied in the past other subject in mathematics different than number theory): is an excellent and great project this book of unsolved problems in number theory (the book seems to me incredible for its quality and is inspiring for me).

Comment: It is known that for $f(x)=e^{104}$ there are infinitely many $f(x)$-almost-primes $n$ such that both $n-2$ and $n-6$ are prime.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @JovanRadenkovic and help improving this thread of posts.

Comment: However, this is only the second iteration of a descent in a proof of Schinzel's hypothesis H using a hypothetical density sieve, so my last comment is conditional on density sieve. In fact, density sieve implies Schinzel's hypothesis H.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looking at primorials, one can look at so-called *admissible sets*. We say that a set of integers $S = \{h_1, \cdots, h_k\}$ is *admissible* if for all primes $p$, $S \pmod{p}$ is not a complete set of residues. Note that for all $p > |S|$, $S \pmod{p}$ is automatically not a full set of residues.

For example, the set $\{1,2\}$ is not admissible since modulo 2 the set represents a complete set of residues, whereas $\{0,2\}$ is admissible.

The conjecture then (originally attributed to Hardy-Littlewood) that for any admissible set $S$, there exists infinitely many integers $n$ such that each of $n + h_1, n + h_2, \cdots, n + h_k$ is prime. In fact the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjectures predicts an asymptotic formula for the number of such $n \leq X$.

This conjecture, of course, is totally out of reach. What is known is due to the seminal work of Yitang Zhang, James Maynard and the two polymath projects: that for for $h_i \geq 0$ for $i = 1, \cdots, k$ and $h_i < h_j$ for $i < j$, whenever $h_k - h_1 \geq 246$ there exists infinitely many $n$ such that there exists two indices $i < j$ such that $n + h_i, n + h_j$ are both prime.

Maynard also proved the following which is out of reach using Zhang's approach: for each positive integer $m$ there exists a number $B(m)$ such that whenever $S$ is an admissible set of size $k$ exceeding $B(m)$, there exists infinitely many $n$ such that $n + h_i$ is prime for at least $m$ indices $i$. In fact, one can take $B(m) = O(e^{4m}m^3)$.

These results are known as *bounded gaps between primes*. They represent an extremely high achievement in prime number theory in recent times, perhaps the greatest results in a generation.

Comment: However, the location of the admissible set is an important element of this problem. As fat as I know Maynard's work does not say how close the n are to each other, much less where they are.  Gerhard "Where Is The Smallest One?" Paseman, 2020.05.01.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "location" of the admissible set. For each $k$ one can compute an admissible set having cardinality $k$; this is an easy exercise for small $k$ but non-trivial even for $k$ in the hundreds (indeed, the admissible set given in Maynard's original paper was computed by Andrew Sutherland). The goal is to find admissible sets of a given cardinality of the smallest diameter, i.e., minimizing $h_k - h_1$. 

It is true that none of the techniques that work actually tell you which indices are prime for a given $n$ which guarantee at least two indices will be prime.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao, the locations of admissible $k-$tuples are hard to find, please if you have more informations about this can you answer my question about this problem : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358119/the-number-of-admissible-tuples-with-last-element-equal-to-h-k-1

Comment: The  admissible set in Maynard is a finite set independent of n. The admissible set in the problem depends on n, and is relatively close to the origin.  Given an admissible set and an n which witnesses it, can you assure me there is no smaller witness?  Gerhard "I Don't Think Maynard Can" Paseman, 2020.05.01.

Comment: It seems @GerhardPaseman , if I understand well the mentioned person, that he was awarded with other prestigious prize, see the article *2020 Frank Nelson Cole Prize in Number Theory*, from the section *From the Secretary* of Notices Of The American Mathematical Society (April 2020). This is just as an invitation if you want to read this good journal, that I suppose that you know, and if you want to see my recent updated post on this MathOverflow *What work can be done to study the solutions of* $\varphi\left(x^{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)^x\right)=2^{x-1} x^{3x-1}\varphi(x)$ *?* Good day!

Answer (score 1):

I will extend  Stanley Yao Xiao definition of admissible k-tuple.

Your conjecture is not true if we arrive to a $k-$tuple not admissible!

Suppose that the $m-$tuple $(0,h_1,\cdots,h_m)$ not admissible, then for $k>m$ and $a > 0$ if you put values $a, a+h_1,a+h_2,\cdots,a+h_{m-1}$ in the $k-$tuple, it will never be admissible!

Your conjecture will stop with the first not admissible $k-$tuple:

$n=9 : 3+(0, 4)$

$n=25 : 19+(0, 4)$

$n=43 : 13+(0, 24, 28)$

$n=49 : 19+(0, 24, 28)$

---

For $N_k < n \leq N_{k+1}$, you have a unique $k-$tuple $(0,h_1,\cdots,h_{k-1})$ and the next $(k+1)-$tuple will be of the form $(0,b,b+h_1,\cdots,b+h_{k-1})$