# The number of admissible tuples with last element equal to $h_{k-1}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $k \geq 2$ and $(h_1, h_2,\cdots,h_{k-1}) \in \mathbb{N}^{k-1}$.

Consider the $k$-tuple : $\mathcal{H}_k=(0,h_1,\cdots,h_{k-1})$ with $0<h_1<\cdots<h_{k-1}$.

The $k$-tuple $\mathcal{H}_k$ is **admissible** if and only if there is no **fixed prime number** $q$ dividing $p(p+h_1) \cdots (p+h_{k-1})$ for all $p\in\mathbb{P}, p \geq q$.

**Example 1:** $\mathcal{H}_3 = (0,2,4)$ is not admissible, because $p(p+2)(p+4)$ is always divisible by $3$ when $p\in\mathbb{P}, p \geq 3$.

**Example 2:** $\mathcal{H}_3=(0,2,6)$ is admissible.

---

> **Question:** For a fixed $h_{k-1}$, can we know the exact number of admissible tuples with last element equal to $h_{k-1}$ ?

---

**Example 1:** Let $h_{k-1}=6$, then the admissible tuples are :
$$(0, 6); \ (0,2,6) ; \ (0, 4, 6)$$
**Example 2:** Let $h_{k-1}=8$, then the admissible tuples are :
$$(0,8) ; \ (0, 2, 8) ; \ (0, 6, 8) ; \ (0, 2, 6, 8)$$

Comment: I doubt a formula exists, but you can compute it by computing differences between terms in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A292225).

Comment: These differences (excluding zeros) are given in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A023189).

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu for your answer, the sequence http://oeis.org/A292225 not clear ! the definition of the sequence is : "a(n) gives the total number of admissible tuples starting with 0 in the interval [0, 1, ..., n-1]. " but how a(1)=1, and a(3)=2 !!

Comment: $a(1)=1$ because there is exactly one admissible tuple $(0)$. $a(3)=2$ because you have tuples $(0)$ and $(0,2)$.

Comment: Thanks Wojowu, you have right.

Comment: Maybe you can get a conjectural formula with the final asymptotic given in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132973/would-the-following-conjectures-imply-lim-inf-n-to-inftyp-nk-p-n-ok-lo

Comment: Note also that the $k-1$-tuple formed by the successive differences between elements of an admissible $k$-tuple can be read backwards to get another "derived" such $k-1$-tuple : $(0,2,8)$ gives $(2,6)$ which when reversed corresponds to $(0,6,8)$.

Comment: The answer would depend on how many primes there are smaller than $h_{k-1}$; this already shows that no simple formula is likely to exist. An asymptotic formula might be a reasonable thing to ask for, however

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao, yes we need primes less than $h_{k-1}$ to divine admissible tuples, asymptotic formula will be a great thingh..